# MSAccess: Select * Into for CSV file in a different Path

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to copy CSV data into an Access table.  TransferText works as expected, but is much slower than "Select * Into".  500K records, 43 columns (not my data).

The following works as needed, but only when the CSV file resides on the same Path as the database (strPath, in this case).

```
strFile = "testfile.csv"
strPath = CurrentProject.Path
strPath2 = CurrentProject.Path & "\Backend_Data\"

strSQL = "SELECT * INTO TempItem FROM [Text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited(,);Database=" & strPath & "].[" & strFile & "];"
db.Execute (strSQL)
```

The CSV file will be landing in strPath2 (\Backend_Data).  Adding strPath2 to strSQL above, in front of strFile, does not work or complain.

Is this a SQL syntax issue, or do I just need to keep the CSV File in the same Path as the database?

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentProject.Path` does not have a trailing backslash, so try with:

```
strPath2 = CurrentProject.Path & "\Backend_Data"

strSQL = "SELECT * INTO TempItem FROM [Text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited(,);Database=" & strPath2 & "].[" & strFile & "];"
db.Execute (strSQL)
```

Comment: Gustav, strFile = strPath2 & strFile is what I tried & fails.  The trailing backslash would be necessary in strPath2,

Comment: Yes, that will fail. Just replace `strPath` with `strPath2` - see extended answer, please.